# How to split a single line into multiple lines on a web page (HTML) so that it would not be inside text box?

Tags: html

I want to split a single line into multiple lines on a web page (HTML), but it should not be inside text box. Can anyone suggest me the tag to be used other than textarea?

Comment: post code and explain what you want to achieve

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide some code...

Comment: Actually i wanted to know, Is there any other tag similar to textarea which can be used to display the multilines without showing the textbox or is there any provision under the textarea tag to hide the textbox. I am actually working on javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a div, you can use this HTML attribute to make it like Textarea(editable)

```
 <div contenteditable="true">Anything is editable</div>
```

To make it look like textarea You can add css as shown below

```
          <div style="width:200px;height:100px;" contenteditable="true">Text </div>
```

You can split text inside div editable into multiple lines.

Or you can style textarea like

```
        <textarea style="border: 0px; resize: none;" rows="4" cols="50">
         Text Area</textarea>
```

this will change the look of the textarea. Add css as you want and change its style.

In a div you can put multi-line text by using 
 tag

```
            <div> Line1 <br>Line2 <br>Line3 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you friends for the response.

Comment: Actually i wanted to know, Is there any other tag similar to textarea which can be used to display the multilines without showing the textbox or is there any provision under the textarea tag to hide the textbox. I am actually working on javascript.

Comment: @GOKULGOPINATHAN you can style it like `<textarea style="border: 0px;
  resize: none;" rows="4" cols="50">Text Area</textarea>` this wont look like textarea. Add css as you want and change its style.  In a **div** you can put multi-line text by using `<br>` tag   `<div> Line1 <br>Line2 <br>Line3 </div>`

Comment: thanks...it worked, but can you please explain me how can i change the fonts, style, etc. since i am new to this.

Comment: @GOKULGOPINATHAN Go to [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) it will help you. And don't forget to mark this as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Give `input[type="text"]` a fixed height e.g 100px ans set `word-break` to `break-word;`

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
input[type="text"]{
  height: 100px;
  word-break: break-word;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="sth">
</body>
</html>
```

But you shouldn't use `input[type="text"]` for that. `textarea` is meant for multiline text fields, this is just a dirty hack. It looks bad and isn't a cross-browser solution. https://jsfiddle.net/3uetz3fc/
EDIT:

```
input[type="text"], textarea{
  outline: none !important;
  border: none !important ;
  background-color: transparent !important ;
  color: inherit !important ;
}
```

Comment: Actually i wanted to know, Is there any other tag similar to textarea which can be used to display the multilines without showing the textbox or is there any provision under the textarea tag to hide the textbox. I am actually working on javascript.

Comment: @GOKULGOPINATHAN I don't think using HTML elements is the solution, if it's the different styling you're after. Instead, I'd use CSS, like in ^this example